# "Inconsistent WhatsApp Web Integration: Error with Manifest File Null Value Reading"

Tags: reactjs, node.js, chromium, whatsapp

I have a project that integrates WhatsApp Web using the following instruction:

```
const client=require('./../../../../New folder/history1/whatsapp-web.js-main/example');
```

Previously, this instruction imported the example.js file which launched WhatsApp Web and worked normally. However, now when I run my project, it opens the WhatsApp Web window, then after 3 seconds, the window disappears, and I get this error in my project's console:

```
 const version = indexHtml.match(/manifest-([\d\\.]+)\.json/)[1];
                                                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
    at LocalWebCache.persist (C:\Users\NEXT4-PC\Desktop\New_folder\New folder\history1\whatsapp-web.js-main\src\webCache\LocalWebCache.js:35:69)
    at C:\Users\NEXT4-PC\Desktop\New_folder\New folder\history1\whatsapp-web.js-main\src\Client.js:761:36
```

What's puzzling is that this setup worked previously, but suddenly stopped functioning. Interestingly, when I run WhatsApp Web independently, it works fine, but when integrated into my project, it fails without any code changes.

Despite my efforts to troubleshoot this error, I haven't found a solution. I seek an explanation and a resolution for this perplexing issue.